# Cisco NAT failing on 3700 series

Tags: routing, nat, cisco

I recently fubared the public interface to an SSH connection. I'm trying to set up a NAT that will forward to the `eth1` interface with a local address.

The set up is a cisco 3750 -> 3560 switch -> servers. All hosts are pingble via the router.

The NAT is being set up similar to this:

```
int fa0/0.1
ip address 10.0.200.1
ip nat inside

int gig0/0
ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ip nat outside

ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet1/0 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.0.200.150 22  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 22 extendable

access-list 1 permit 10.0.200.0 0.0.0.255
```

With `show ip nat translations` I can see the mapping. When the public IP is nmap'd it comes up as `22/filtered` and I'm not allowed to connect.

With lft(layer 4 traceroute), i.e. `lft <ip>:22` the router and the switch behind it return nothing but the server comes back with open.

Its as if the NAT *almost* works.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cisco 3750 does not support NAT](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a008011c629.shtml#topic1).